# MySQL: Copy selected tables to new db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to find a way to copy selected tables in an existing db to a newly created one.

Either in phpMyAdmin or with the help of .php.

I prefer not to use export as it messes up my charsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE db.table;

INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM db.table;
```

where db.table is the table that you want to replicate.

Using PHP

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new_database", 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_database.old_table; INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM old_database.old_table");

$sth->execute();
```

Comment: this seems to be working in phpMyAdmin - thx!

How would I do in order to do this in php? Do I need to connect to both db's?

Comment: No. You have to connect to one database. It doesn't matter which, as long as you refer to the other like database_name.table_name

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE database_name.target_tocopy_table;
```

1. new_table is according to name of new table that you want to make.
2. database_name is the active database(currently used).
3. target_tocopy_table is table that you want to copy.

Example: you want to copy user_table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_copy LIKE user_table;
```

Comment: Please post some explanation of your code, especially for newbies who might not understand what it does.

Comment: My code method is the same with @tliokos above. He did it faster! But if you need some description...alright. new_table is the name of table that you want to create and target_tocopy_table is the table that you want to copy. Pretty simple right?

Comment: Your answer got flagged for length and content, which is why I left the comment. Please edit your answer and add the description you just posted, and that should prevent your answer from being flagged. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your notification pal...I just did it as your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using phpMyAdmin, you could also do this graphically without having to write (or copy/paste) any SQL code. From the Operations tab of the table, there's an area for "Copy table to (database.table).

[image: phpMyAdmin copy table interface]

You could also copy the entire database over (from the database page, go to the Operations tab and look for "Copy database to:"